# Angular ng build prerendered routes like angular universal for static serving (with open graph og tags)

Tags: angular, facebook-opengraph, server-side-rendering, angular-universal

Is it possible to build an angular app (angular 2/3/4/5) for production (with AoT) with several prerendered routes? I'm thinking of something similar to angular universal just during the build process for predefined routes.

For example:

```
./dist/index.html << this is default!
// Additional build prerendered index.html files for specified routes
./dist/routeA/index.html
./dist/routeB/index.html
./dist/routeC/customRouteParam/index.html
```

#### Why static prerendering of Angular?

- Static Serving from s3
- Avoiding extra complexity of server-side rendering
- Keep advantages of universal app and serverside rendering
- Improving load time
- Support for Open Graph Tags (OG Tags)

#### Serverside Rendering with Angular Universal

I do know serverside prerendering is possible with angular universal however I'd like to avoid this extra complexity and rather host fully static. For anyone who is interested in angular universal serverside rendering the following resources may be useful:

- [Angular Universal](https://universal.angular.io/)
- [Angular Universal server-side rendering serverless with AWS Lambda - boilderplate](https://github.com/maciejtreder/angular-universal-pwa)
- [Angular Universal server-side rendering - boilerplate](https://github.com/ng-seed/universal)
- [Angular Open Graph Meta Tag Support](https://github.com/fulls1z3/ngx-meta)

Comment: Looking through Angular build options this seems not to be possible as of now. I added an issue in the angular git repository: https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/21307

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do prerendering with universal and then just serve the html files statically

The starter kit has a sample file, prerender.ts, showing how it's done.
https://github.com/angular/universal-starter.

You just need to provide a list of known routes to prerender, then server side rendering is performed and the resulting html is saved to disk.

I used this approach for a website where content only changes every few months and it's quite fast

Comment: Thx David! Exactly what I was looking for!